# Render to element inserted to DOM by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

In my app I use AJAX to fetch a specific view (template) file and append it to the DOM using jQuery on page load:

```
$.get('/ajax/load/myview', function(view) {
    siteFetchComplete();
    $('#container').append(view);
});
```

There are various elements in the view that I would like to reference and render to using `React`. For example, to load a series of helpdesk tickets I might do something like:

```
function siteFetchComplete() {
    var TicketBox = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <h1>Helpdesk Tickets</h1>
            );
        }
    });

    React.render(
        <TicketBox />,
        $('#tickets')
    );
}
```

where `$('#tickets')` is an element that was appended after the AJAX request processed.

How do I reference `$('#tickets')` when calling `React.render`? Currently I receive a `Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.` error because React can't see the element when called this way.

Comment: No problem as long as you call React.render after the ajax request before it inserting $('tickets') completes. When React.render runs it will see the DOM contents at that moment and it will find tickets DOM element.

Comment: I updated my code...you're saying something like that should work? I call my React code before I manipulate the DOM with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a jQuery wrapper object to React instead of a DOM element. Instead you should unwrap it using jQuery's `get()` method and pass the raw DOM object to React:

```
$('#tickets').get(0) // returns the DOM element
```

Also move the call to `siteFetchComplete()` to *after* the `append()` operation, otherwise jQuery will be trying to find the element before it exists!

Comment: That seems very obvious now that it's in front of me...thanks!